# Font not loading due to cross origin error despite cross origin header and local file

Tags: error, cross-origin

I have a CMS which uses tinymce with elfinder.  On the computer of one of my clients elfinder wont load. I checked it on his computer and the only thing I can find is this error:

> Font from origin has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access.

It is a local file on the server and I already added this to the *.htaccess* file in the root:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>    
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
</IfModule>
```

What should I do?  There are errors in the elfinder code because this file doesn't load.

Comment: Can you give us a link to the site so we can test it?

Answer (score 1):

In your `.htaccess` file, try:

```
<FilesMatch ".(eot|svg|otf|ttf|woff)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: it's a javascript file that wont load, someone changed my title sorry